# While loop regex from file

Tags: regex, arrays, bash, loops, while-loop

Can anyone see what I have done wrong here? This a fairly complex process so let me take a moment to spell it all out. I have a directory called "databases". Inside that directory are several files such as "lan.db", "wan.db", etc. The script below first takes every file it finds in the databases directory and puts the file names into an array. The script then opens each individual file and reads line by line (ignoring commented out lines). For this question, I'm using an IP database. The script opens for example lan.db and reads line by line. Each line (less commented out lines) contains one IPv4 address and one IPv6 address seperated by a |. The script then compares the line it reads against a regex expression to validate the addresses. (Note, this is just a simple IPv4 regex statement. Yes 999.999.999.999 is not technically valid. Irrelevant for this question though). For some reason, the script is not making the regex comparison. What am I doing wrong here?

```
shopt -s nullglob
DBARRAY=(databases/*)
local i
for i in "${!DBARRAY[@]}"; do
  cat ${DBARRAY[$i]} | grep -v \# | while read LINE; do 
    local IPV4="^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}+\|"
    local IPV6="[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}$"
    DBREGEX="$IPV4$IPV6"
    if [[ ( $LINE =~ $DBREGEX ) ]]; then echo "FAIL"; fi 
  done
done
```

I know you're going to ask, "Why did you split up the regex?" This is only part of the entire regex expression. This is checking a | delimited file and I just wanted to put each part of regex on its own line so it would fit on screen while editing and so its easier to read and modify each part individually.

I have done similar work elsewhere in my script which works great. I can't figure out what I have coded wrong here. Thanks for the help!

*** UPDATE ***

Peter pointed out some things below. Therefore I'm updating the code slightly so it makes more sense.

```
shopt -s nullglob
DBARRAY=(databases/*)
i=0
for i in "${!DBARRAY[@]}"; do
  cat ${DBARRAY[$i]} | grep -v \# | while read LINE; do 
    IPV4="^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}+\|"
    IPV6="[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}$"
    DBREGEX="$IPV4$IPV6"
    if [[ ( $LINE =~ $DBREGEX ) ]]; then echo "CHEESE"; fi 
  done
done
```

*** UPDATE ***

Ok so I may have finally discovered the disconnect... however it makes NO sense. Before I try to explain let me post up the code again, but this time with some small changes. I have trimmed it down to highlight the problem area. I also have to add some of the real code that you didn't originally see in order for this to make any sense.

```
Comment Out shopt -s nullglob
Comment Out DBARRAY=(databases/*)
Comment Out i=0
Comment Out   for i in "${!DBARRAY[@]}"; do
Comment Out     cat ${DBARRAY[$i]} | grep -v \# | while read LINE; do 

                IPV4="^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\|"
                IPV6="[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}$"
                DBREGEX="$IPV4$IPV6"
                LINE="1.1.1.1|f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f"
                if [[ !( $LINE =~ $DBREGEX ) ]]; then RETURN="fail" && ERROR="This is the error message that gets reported back!"; return; fi 

Comment Out   done
Comment Out done
```

Notice is this version I have commented out all the loops and we're "simulating" a line from the database. In this example above, the line being simulated from the database is valid. This would be an invalid example: LINE="XXXXXXXX1.1.1.1|f:f:f:f:f:f:f:f"

Now lets say we put the bad example from above in the database and uncomment out the while loop, it suddenly fails... BUT! WAIT! First some more code: (Just for reference, note how I statically added the file location since the first loop is still commented out)

```
Comment Out shopt -s nullglob
Comment Out DBARRAY=(databases/*)
Comment Out i=0
Comment Out   for i in "${!DBARRAY[@]}"; do
                cat databases/lan.db | grep -v \# | while read LINE; do 

                IPV4="^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\|"
                IPV6="[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}$"
                DBREGEX="$IPV4$IPV6"
                if [[ !( $LINE =~ $DBREGEX ) ]]; then RETURN="fail" && ERROR="This is the error message that gets reported back!"; return; fi 

              done
Comment Out done
```

Here is the really weird part. If I echo out $LINE, its getting it from the database properly but it apparently is failing the comparison. So even though $LINE is set properly, it still seems to fail the comparison in the IF statement. At least that's what appears to be happening. Is this weird? Or is it just me?

Comment: Did I stump everyone lol? Someone please help. Do I need to be more clear?

Comment: Are you using this code inside of a function? I get an error when I try to run it from the shell as is (i.e. due to the use of `local`).

Comment: How are you concluding that it's not making the regex comparison? Do you realize that you've got it set up now to echo FAIL upon _success_?

Comment: Yes and Yes. This part of the code was pulled out of a function. Just delete "local". I'll edit the code above. Also yes, it actually does some other things upon success or fail, but I pulled all that code out to simplify my question. As a place holder I just echoed something without thinking (quickly put fail). Just disregard the "fail". Point is, even when inverting the if statement, it still doesn't seem to work. I'll update code.

Comment: Please clarify what "doesn't seem to work" means. In particular, can you confirm that the regex expression _is_ getting evaluated and that you're just surprised by the fact that it doesn't succeed/fail as you'd expect? Or is it not getting executed?

Comment: Yes I have tested the entire regex including individual pieces of it. I also validated the regex with a web based validator. When I enter a properly formatted line in the db file, it appears to succeed. When I enter an incorrect line in the database it still seems to succeed. It feels like the comparison in the IF statement is not taking place at all.

Comment: I may have figured it out... I'm gonna look like a real fool too...

Comment: Hmm interesting. Good point.

Comment: So I think its working fine. I was able to verify this with some other stuff removed. It appears to be working and just some other part of my code is fudging it all up. Will update when I know more.

Comment: You're probably right, however that may be an unforeseen error thus far. Kudos for catching that early. I think I finally discovered the disconnect point. I'll try to explain above, but it requires a little extra code. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Tested both ways and the results are the same. I'm sure that's probably an issue as well, but I have narrowed the issue down to the while loop $LINE variable. For example, I can use a completely different regex, or even just a simple variable comparison and it fails there too. At this point, the issue is not with the regex.

Comment: FYI, after reading your update and comments, I see that the lines are supposed to contain _both_ the ipv4 and ipv6 addresses and the `|` was _supposed_ to be a literal. I apologize for going on about that and have deleted my answer and related comments. I'm afraid I don't have any ideas given your latest experience and can only suggest reposting a question with the smalltest test case you can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong regexp syntax for "OR".  Use `"|"` instead of `"\|"`.

Examples:

```
$ [[ abc =~ (abc|def) ]] && echo match || echo nomatch
match
$ [[ abef =~ (abc|def) ]] && echo match || echo nomatch
nomatch
$ [[ def =~ (abc|def) ]] && echo match || echo nomatch
match
$ [[ def =~ (abc\|def) ]] && echo match || echo nomatch
nomatch
$ [[ abc =~ (abc\|def) ]] && echo match || echo nomatch
nomatch
```